# White character C# textbox

Tags: c#, sockets

I am new in C# and I have a problem with square white characters in textbox in C#. (see screenshot below)
I have implemented client-server program for chatting which is supported by `System.Net.Sockets.` Inside each program is `byte[] array= new byte[10025]`, which is never totally full, but textbox shows blank characters inside. Can you help me with deletion of this characters?

Thank you!
[image: Blank white character squares]

Read code of client side: 
http://pastebin.com/W3Pc3BPG

```
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                int buffSize = 0;
                byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
                string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream);
                readData = "" + returndata;
                msg();
            }
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            ctThread.Join();
        }
```

Comment: When you read from a socket, the return from the `Read` method will be an integer containing the number of bytes you read. You *must* respect this number - the rest of the characters in `array` will be garbage. If you update the post with your socket reading code, we can suggest the suitable fix (but basically, it's "Only take the correct number of characters from `array`)

Comment: You have an encoding issue.  If you are using a Textbox replace with RichTextBox.  If you are using any stream make sure the encoding is UTF8.  The default is ASCII which will change non printable characters.  You also may have Unicode Characters an may need to use Unicode (not UTF8).

Comment: can you post the code of your communication procedure?

Comment: @RB - Thank you, I have already tried with function clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize(), but then there nothing happens at the client side (server side log the message successfully).

Comment: @ZanPokerznik I've posted the correct way to use the [Stream.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) method - respecting the number of bytes read. In the future, it is advisable to edit your question with the code inline, rather than on an external web-site though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
int buffSize = 0;
byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
// Make sure you respect the number of bytes that have been read.
// Note that the below code is not the most performant - it's just
// to demonstrate the technique. 
int bytesRead = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
byte[] theData = inStream.Take(bytesRead).ToArray();
string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(theData);
readData = "" + returndata;
msg();
```

Comment: Thank you once more time! Now I understand and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code on textbox to check if that is white space.

```
bool hasAllWhitespace = txtBox1.Text.Length>0 &&
                        txtBox1.Text.Trim().Length==0;
```

---

To eliminate spaces

```
if (hasAllwhitespace)
{
    txtBox1.Text.Trim();
}
```